# Use site title as default value in text or calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-2010, default-value, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I would like to set up a site column that will by default show the site title.  This should be done by either setting the default value of a single line of text field or using a calculated field.  I will use the field value in workflows.  I have tried using [Site Name] and [Site Title] but this produces an error.  Is there an identifier or lookup I can use to retrieve this property?  I'm using SharePoint 2010 and SPD 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats not possible with standard functionality.
But you can achieve your goal with the SPD.

First edit your masterpage and include a new script tag for jQuery inside the head tag. I would recommend to upload the current version to a document library e.g. style library.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now add this script also to the masterpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var web = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize, "sp.js");       
});

function initialize() {
    if ($("input[title='CurrentSiteTitle']").length > 0) {
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = context.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
    }
}

function onSuccess() {
    $("input[title='CurrentSiteTitle']").val(web.get_title());
}
</script>
```

Add a new site column and name it fancy like 'CurrentSiteTitle' (single line of text). For some reason I couldn't make it work with the Id.